# Git is failing to push in puttycyg because of SSH error

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin, puttycyg

I've been using puttycyg as a Cygwin terminal for my rails development. I've set up a git repository on a project management website and now I want to push my code to it with the following command:

```
git push origin master
```

I'm getting  the following error:

```
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

I know ssh is used for authentication but I don't know if I need to set anything up to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problems was that I didn't have SSH installed with Cygwin. I ran the Cygwin setup.exe file again and when asked to select packages I searched for ssh and checked all I found:

[image]

Once this was done I was getting authentication errors so I used the `ssh-keygen` command to generate the required keys, [instructions on how do this](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html).

Answer (score 1):

My bet is you need to install OpenSSH. Try reading [OpenSSH and PuTTY](http://linux-sxs.org/networking/openssh.putty.html). It's a decent guide to installing / configuring it for a Windows enviornment and setting up SSH keys, something you'll need with git.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a read, looks like a lot to it but at least I might learn something.

Comment: Learning's always good. Once you get the basics (key generation in particular) down it's not hard at all to repeat.